# How to make angular wait for a function to return a value before proceeding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function like this:

```
$scope.process = function(){
     $http().success(){
         return something;   
     }
};
```

Just assume that the code is complete.. and then when I call it

```
alert($scope.process());
```

it displays undefined.

How do I get the angular to wait for the return of the function before proceeding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. Instead, you tell it what to do when the response is available:

```
$scope.process = function() {
    $http.get(path).success(function(data) {
        alert("I just received " + data);
    });
};
```

Or, if you want this to be configurable:

```
$scope.process = function(callback) {
    $http.get(path).success(callback);
};
```